# javascript: How to override a method for all the instances of some class?

Tags: javascript, oop, aop

```
function Person(){
    this.scream = function(){
        alert('NO NO NO!!!!');
    };
}

var steve = new Person();
steve.scream() // NO NO NO!!!!
Person.prototype.scream = function(){
    alert('YES YES YES!!!!');
}
steve.scream() // still NO NO NO!!!!
```

Is there a way to override '***scream***' without referencing steve explicitly? Think about the cases when  you have may instances of ***Person***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

Having that `Person` declaration, every time you create a new "instance" of it the "constructor" will run and you'll create a completely new `scream` function (closure) which you don't have any reference to, except from the newly created object, `steve.scream` that is.

As an alternative you may do it like this:

```
function Person(){}

Person.prototype.scream = function(){
    alert('NO NO NO!!!!');
}

var steve = new Person();
steve.scream() // NO NO NO!!!!
Person.prototype.scream = function(){
    alert('YES YES YES!!!!');
}
steve.scream() // this time is YES YES YES!!!!
```

In which case the initial `scream` "method" is available only in one place, on the prototype, and you can overwrite it for all "instances".

Answer (score 1):

```
function Person(){};
Person.prototype.scream = function(){ alert('NO NO NO!!!!'); };
var steve = new Person();
steve.scream();
Person.prototype.scream = function(){alert('YES YES YES!!!!');};
steve.scream();
```

Answer (score 0):

and, if you want to continue to use your code style, you may like

```
function Person(){
    this.constructor.prototype.scream = function(){
        alert('NO NO NO!!!!');
    };
}
var steve = new Person();
steve.scream();
Person.prototype.scream = function(){ alert('YES YES YES!!!!'); };
steve.scream();
```

Comment: this is different BTW, probably wrong, because the constructor chain will alter your prototypes

Comment: Also, access to closure is corrupted. The scream function is common to all the instances, while closure should be per instance.